# Issues with Building AC Generator

Tags: generator, ac

So we are trying to build an AC generator, an alternator, if you will. We are using a 5" PVC pipe for the body with a hole drilled diametrically, through which a bolt passes. Inside of this pipe, on the bolt, we have a six pole rotor magnet, which rotates as we rotate the bolt. We then have 18 gauge, plastic coated wire wrapped around the pipe. We used a drill to spin the magnet at respectable speeds, but were not able to get any electrical outputs. Are there any glaring issues in this design? If so, how can we address them?

The first image is of the inside of the generator, showing the rotor magnet (apologies for the image). The second is of the outside of the generator, showing the wire wrappings. The bare copper wire is shown there to test an unprotected wire and is not used in the actual design.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So many questions, but first a photo helps a lot

Comment: excessive gap  rotor and stator  with insufficient turns on coils with insufficient RPM